# Regular Expressions Validation in Google Forms MMM.YYYY

Tags: regex, forms, google-forms

I would like to set a regular expressions validation in Google Forms, but I don´t know how to set this.

I looked in the **Google Help Center** (https://support.google.com/a/answer/1371417) but I didn´t understand anything (*PS: I don´t know how to code yet*)

The regular expression should follow **MMM.YYYY**, i.e. **Mar.2020**, **Dec.2031**, **Feb.2005**.

Could you please, help me with this topic?

Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome Sandro. So for a regular expression, the format's something like

- 3 letters
- 1 "."
- 4 digits

Something like this should work:

```
[a-zA-Z]{3}\.[0-9]{4}
```

`[a-zA-Z]{3}` means "any letter between a-z, and also allow upper case A-Z, and it has to be exactly 3 of those"

We have to escape the `.` with the `\` otherwise the regex treats it as a wildcard that could be anything.  We just want specifically a `.`

`[0-9]{4}`  means "it has to be exactly 4 digits"

We could be more precise, for example if you know the letters always have to be:

- one uppercase letter
- followed by two lowercase letters

You could then do:

```
[A-Z][a-z]{2}\.[0-9]{4}
```

If you know the month is always going to be one of Jan/Feb/Mar etc, you could restrict it further to just those, otherwise it'll allow entries like XXX.2020

```
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\.[0-9]{4}
```

You could even do something on the digits, e.g. if you know it's always going to start with 19 or 20 perhaps, you could do:

```
(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)\.(19|20)[0-9]{2}
```

So `(19|20)[0-9]{2}` allows for either 19 or 20, and then it has to be followed by another 2 digits, i.e. allowing for anything between 1900 - 2099

Comment: Hi Duncan, 
Thank you very much.
It´s helped a lot